# Why lazy loading does not work in razor views (cshtml files)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

I write following statements in my cshtml file:-

```
@{
string categoryName = string.Format("{0}->{1}", label.Category.Parent.Name,
label.Category.Name);
@categoryName
}
```

and get an exception `Object reference null`.

On the other hand the same works in the Controller.cs file and in the immediate window too. I know it is related to lazy loading.

Is there any concept behind it, that it does not work in Expressions in Cshtml files ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work because your context is disposed by the time your code is executed. All data should be loaded in your view so turn lazy loading off and use eager loading. Call .Single() on your results to force the load plus use: from o in context.Labels.Include(o=>o.Parent) for example to force the loading at that time. You could also flatten out these results into a view model in your controller.

Comment: But, when we put break point in the cshtml file, and then execute this in immediate window, we get results. By this time also, the controller has executed. Why do we get results here then ?

Comment: not sure if being in debug mode makes a difference  here with the object lifetime I wouldnt imagine it does - but I do know this is one of the problems when starting with MVC : ) Load ALL data and pass it to the view. This is a rule that should always be followed regardless of if things seem to work otherwise. The controllers job is to orchestrate all data to hand it off to the view.