# ApplicationUser.Username is null even though the ApplicationUserId is not

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I'm currently facing a problem with a NullException. I'm getting the error at `@comment.ApplicationUser.UserName` down below, **but only if I am accesing a comment which was posted by another user rather than the one who uploaded the picture. If I comment to the same picture the user(me) posted it shows the UserName correctly.** I don't really know what could be the problem, since if I call `@comment.ApplicationUserId` everything works as it should displaying the id of the user who posted the image. Shouldn't it be linked automatically to the ApplicationUser object when I call `@comment.ApplicationUser.UserName` ?

**The view where I'm getting the error**

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
{
    <dd class="font-italic">

       @comment.Body commented by @comment.ApplicationUser.UserName

    </dd>
}
```

**The Comment Model**

```
public class Comment
{

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Body { get; set; }

        public bool ApprovedByUser { get; set; }

        public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

        public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

        public Photo Photo { get; set; }

        public int PhotoId { get; set; }

}
```

Every-time I create a new comment into the **CommentsController/Create** I do this

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Body,ApprovedByUser,ApplicationUserId,PhotoId")] Comment comment, int id)
    {

        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db));
        var currentUser = userManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        comment.PhotoId = id;
        comment.ApplicationUserId = currentUser.Id;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Comments.Add(comment);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.PhotoId = new SelectList(db.Photos, "Id", "Title", comment.PhotoId);
        return View(comment);
    }
```

I also have a custom **PhotoCommentsViewModel** containing the photo and the comments for that photo.

```
public class PhotoCommentsViewModel
    {
        public Photo Photo { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    }
```

I get the abobe viewModel from **Photo/Details/{id}** controller here

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            var photo = db.Photos.Find(id);
            var comments = db.Comments.Where(s => s.PhotoId == photo.Id);

            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var viewModel = new PhotoUserViewModel
            {
                Photo = photo,
                Comments = comments,
            };


            if (viewModel.Photo == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Details action, `ApplicationUser` needs to be eagerly loaded with the comments.

```
var comments = db.Comments.Where(s => s.PhotoId == photo.Id).Include(x => x.ApplicationUser).ToList();
```

Further reading on [Loading Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I really appreciate, it works now! Happy New Year and thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

You should use eager loading in this case.

```
 var comments = db.Comments
                .Where(s => s.PhotoId == photo.Id)
                .Include(x =>x.ApplicationUser).ToList();
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441870/why-lazy-loading-does-not-work-in-razor-views-cshtml-files)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I didn't know about eager loading! Happy New Year and thanks again!